# How to use a SQL2000 Linked Server to query an Oracle 11G table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, linked-server

How can I construct the SQL that I need to query the Projects_dim table using the Linked Server "idwd"?

To test the connection, I ran a sample query using the linked server name. To access the tables on the linked server, I used a four-part naming syntax:

linked_server_name.catalog_ name.schema_name.table_name.

replacing the values, you get:

```
idwd.idwd.wimr.PROJECTS_DIM
```

of should it be the following?

```
idwd..wimr.PROJECTS_DIM
```

The database name is "idw" but the grid below shows a blank value under "catalog", which is one source of my confusion, though I believe that the more likely approach is to construct the syntax assuming that the catalog part of the qualified table name should be blank as in the following first example.

```
    select * from idwd..wimr.PROJECTS_DIM
    
    Server: Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
    OLE DB provider 'idwd' does not contain table '"wimr"."PROJECTS_DIM"'.  The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

select * from idwd.idwd.wimr.PROJECTS_DIM

Server: Msg 7312, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid use of schema and/or catalog for OLE DB provider 'MSDAORA'. A four-part name was supplied, but the provider does not expose the necessary interfaces to use a catalog and/or schema.
```

What do I need to do to query this table?

I am using the MS OLEDB Driver for Oracle.

I thought perhaps there is an issue with case-sensitivity, so I tried this:

```
select * from IDWD..WIMR.PROJECTS_DIM


Server: Msg 7356, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
OLE DB provider 'MSDAORA' supplied inconsistent metadata for a column. Metadata information was changed at execution time.
```

and this:

```
select * from IDWD.IDWD.WIMR.PROJECTS_DIM

Server: Msg 7312, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid use of schema and/or catalog for OLE DB provider 'MSDAORA'. A four-part name was supplied, but the provider does not expose the necessary interfaces to use a catalog and/or schema.
```

I tried to create a linked server using each of the two likely drivers:

1. Microsoft OLEDB Provider for
   Oracle
2. Oracle Provider for OLEDB

..without luck.

Could it be a driver issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may be on the right track thinking about this as an issue of case sensitivity. Quoting from the Microsoft support document [**How to set up and troubleshoot a linked server to an Oracle database in SQL Server**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/280106/en-us) regarding errors 7312, 7313, 7314:

> If you receive these error messages, a
>   table may be missing in the Oracle
>   schema or you may not have permissions
>   on that table. Verify that the schema
>   name has been typed by using
>   uppercase. The alphabetical case of
>   the table and of the columns should be
>   as specified in the Oracle system
>   tables.
>
> On the Oracle side, a table or a
>   column that is created without double
>   quotation marks is stored in
>   uppercase. If the table or the column
>   is enclosed in double quotation marks,
>   the table or the column is stored as
>   is.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this issue. Oracle was probably upgraded recently if it did worked before.

To resolve I connected to Oracle and did a "descr TABLENAME;" and check whatever column was in problem. In my case, I had a column type as NUMBER without any scale like in this preview.

[image: Preview]

I asked a DBA to force a scale for these 3 columns and problem is now solved!

But I did find also there is a workaround this solution. You can also change the TSQL

from

```
SELECT * FROM idwd..wimr.PROJECTS_DIM
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(idwd,'select * from wimr.PROJECTS_DIM')
```

And Microsoft Support report a problem if nullability is not set on a column.

More info about my [search on Google](https://www.google.ca/search?q=The%20OLE%20DB%20provider%20%22MSDAORA%22%20for%20linked%20server%20supplied%20inconsistent%20metadata%20for%20a%20column.%20The%20column%20%28compile-time%20ordinal%20499%29%20of%20object%20%20was%20reported%20to%20have%20at%20compile%20time%20and%205%20at%20run%20time.&oq=The%20OLE%20DB%20provider%20%22MSDAORA%22%20for%20linked%20server%20supplied%20inconsistent%20metadata%20for%20a%20column.%20The%20column%20%28compile-time%20ordinal%20499%29%20of%20object%20%20was%20reported%20to%20have%20at%20compile%20time%20and%205%20at%20run%20time.&aqs=chrome.0.57j64l2.56777&sugexp=chrome,mod=13&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=The%20OLE%20DB%20provider%20%22MSDAORA%22%20for%20linked%20server%20supplied%20inconsistent%20metadata%20for%20a%20column.&oq=The%20OLE%20DB%20provider%20%22MSDAORA%22%20for%20linked%20server%20supplied%20inconsistent%20metadata%20for%20a%20column.&gs_l=serp.3..0i30.12533.13703.0.14095.2.2.0.0.0.0.79.152.2.2.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.WIc1b2sszv0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=57ec3b49c73245fc&bpcl=38625945&biw=1440&bih=775).